# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable for eval( )

Tags: python, typeerror, eval

```
def check(positions):
  final = []
  n = len(positions)

  #positions is a list of lists. So now we'll break this into individual lists
  #creating n empty lists

  lists = [[] for _ in range(n)]

  cond =""                             #empty string to create condition

  #fetching lists from list of lists
  for k in range(n):
    lists[k]=positions[k]

  #computation work starts here

  for i in lists[0]:
    for j in range(1,n-1):
      cond+= 'i+j in list[j] and '
    cond+='i+n-1 in list[n-1]'

    for i in lists[0]:
     for j in range(1,n-1):
      if(eval(cond)):
        final.append(i)

  return final
```

I am getting "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable" error on the line containing "if(eval(cond)):". Please explain where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you do not have any variable called `list`, so Python assumes you are referring to the type `list` (think of "type" as "data type" like `int`, `float`, etc..).

I believe you meant to use `i[j]` instead of `list[j]` in your `cond` string. If this is the case, replace `list[j]` by `i[j]` and this should do it.

```
for i in lists[0]:
    for j in range(1,n-1):
        cond+= 'i+j in i[j] and '
    cond+='i+n-1 in i[n-1]'
```

**Side note:** You should not call a variable `list`, as this can conflict with Python's `list` data type and can create a mess.

Comment: Thank you!! I got the mistake. Instead of just "list" while I had declared "lists". And yes it's better to avoid using a variable similar to pre-defined data type.

Comment: @SameekshaGupta Glad this helps! If this answered your question, please consider upvoting/marking this post as answer. Happy coding!